# Solving y in exponentiation

Tags: exponentiation

I'm already long time from school. I want to solve y from this equation:

$x = 10^\frac{(y - 109)}{32}$

How can I do that?

In real life y is the rain intensity, and x is number of millimeters rain per hour.

Comment: Take log base 10 from both sides, and proceed.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{y-109}{32}=\log_{10}x$$ or
$$y=32\log_{10}x+109.$$

Answer (score 0):

Take the (decimal) logarithms of both sides:
$$\frac{y-100}{32}=\log x$$
I think you can easily end the computation.